# What is a good way to get inverted colors for most text-display purposes?

Tags: gnome3, display-settings

My monitor is not the best in the world and I find reading black on white unpleasant. Where I could (gedit, terminal) I changed the colour to something more relaxing for me - like the Kobalt scheme in Gedit, or green on black for the terminal. This helps my eyes.

Now, I wonder what would be the most economical way to get most of my software to display text like this? most economical means that I don't want to tweak the settings of every single program (if can be avoided), most of my software would be iceweasel, liferea and icedove.

I've looked at doing this via a colour scheme (high contrast inverted) in Gnome3 without success - with liferea and icedove, menus and sidebars had the inverted color scheme but the parts where actual text is displayed where still black on white. Maybe there's a better scheme for this purpose?

I'm looking for a way to tweak few settings and achieve a result across many applications. If this is not possible, poit it out and I will aks seprate questions. My setup is Debian stable with Gnome3.

Comment: The 'most economical way'? Most Linux based operating systems and their applications are open-source and free anyway :-) . But I think there are few other high-contrast themes, and can edited slightly from Tweak tool.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider the use of :

```
xcalib -invert -alter
```

this is a binary that will invert the color of your whole screen.
You can also bind this command to a shortcut so that you can activate it on demand.

**Edit 1:**

As it seemes to be browser related, you can also try for example the [official high contrast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph) extension for google Chrome or the [option of firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/accessibility-features-firefox-make-firefox-and-we?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Accessibility#w_using-a-high-contrast-theme)

**Edit 2** *(probably the more unlikly to work on Gnome Shell but still possible on Ubuntu)* :

If you install `compizconfig-settings-manager` on your system you should be able to activate the compiz high contrast plugin who allow according to [this old post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=580652) the use of the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> on the current windows only

[Source: [this blog]](http://www.answeredubuntu.com/181419/how_to_reverse_colors_for_the_current_window_in_gnome_shell)

Comment: Right... At a guess, this will include pictures as well, so people in photos will turn sort of blue...

Comment: Note that this does not work for a multi screen setup. It uses the ancient `XF86VidMode` extension and sets it's modified version of the gamma ramp to the whole display and the X server then decides which screen it will act upon. In contrast to the more sane approach of looping over all screens and applying the gamma ramp on each one (e.g. like `redshift` does).

Comment: Hmm. Works, but I'm not totally happy.

Comment: @mart I add some other option for you thought they are not perfect too.